# Error at partitioning disk

Tags: raid, hard-drive, installation, debian-squeeze

I am struggling to install debian squeeze (64 bit) OS in the system which is having RAID 1. While partitioning the drive, It says an error **Operation not permitted during write on /dev/md126** . I am using IBM System x3250 M4 server model.

For more info about the server:

http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/in/x/hardware/rack/x3250m4/specs.html

Here, You can find the screenshot of the disk partitioning error.

[Screenshot1.png](http://i34.photobucket.com/albums/d137/sat_images/partman_choose_partition_0_zpsf8a35ab7.png)

[Screenshot2.png](http://i34.photobucket.com/albums/d137/sat_images/partman_choose_partition_5_zpse47290fe.png)

[Screenshot3.png](http://i34.photobucket.com/albums/d137/sat_images/partman_confirm_nooverwrite_0_zps3ace5449.png)

[Screenshot4.png](http://i34.photobucket.com/albums/d137/sat_images/partman_exception_handler_0_zpsd91e64e3.png)

Whether squeeze is detecting the RAID ( controller ) or not ?

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

The RAID device is marked as read-only (it's in the super long name for the drive).  That means you can't write, say, a partition map to it :)  Some googling around for what I think is the RAID card name found [the IBM site with some drivers for RHEL](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=migr-5089068).  More google finds [an Ubuntu forums post referencing that card](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1881537&page=2).  If that one is right, your best option may be to go delete the RAID configuration, convince the RAID card to just show each disk to the OS, and soft RAID inside Debian.